# C: Interpret gcc output and numbres

Tags: c

I have written a C program which produces the following output, when running gcc on a Linux VM on Windows:

Error message:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/P91ZT.jpg]

However, the number of "{ and }" should be correct, so that I do not understand why the compiler complains about this. Also I am using k and random after declaring them, how can I get rid of the warnings?

Thank you for your help!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <time.h>
# include <getopt.h>
#include <stdbool.h>

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
   int opt=0;
//Parameter:
//boolean random:
//    typdef enum {false, true} bool;
    bool random=false;
//Zahl zu der gezaehlt werden soll: k
    int k=10;
//Zahl der Kindprozesse, die erzeugt werden sollen: N
    int n=1;
//Parsieren der Kommandozeilenparameter:
    while ((opt = getopt(argc, argv, "nt:")) != -1)
    {
        switch (opt)
        {
        case 'k':
            k = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'n':
            n = atoi(optarg);
            break;
        case 'r':
            random=true;
        default: /* '?' */
            printf("%s", "No valid parameters.");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }
}
        //Erzeugen von n Kindprozessen:
        int zaehlerprozesse=0;
        while(zaehlerprozesse<n)
        {
            fork();
            zaehlerprozesse++;
        }
        if(//TODO list)
    {
        //Kindprozess liegt vor
        int zaehler=1;
        char ausgabe[256]= {0};
            int zaehlen=k;
            //Umgehen mit random:
            if(random==true)
            {
                srand((unsigned) time(&t));
                int help=rand()%(k*0.5);
                //0 oder 1 um zu bestimmen, ob addieren oder substrahieren:
                int luck=rand()%1;
                if(luck==0)
                {
                    zaehlen=zaehlen-help;
                }
                else
                {
                    zaehlen=zaehlen+help;
                }
            }
            while(zaehler<=zaehlen)
            {
                int pid=getpid();
                int ppid=getppid();
                sprintf(ausgabe, "%d %c %d %c %d\n", pid,' ', ppid,' ',zaehler);
                write(STDOUT_FILENO, ausgabe, strlen(ausgabe));
                sleep(1);
                zaehler++;
            }
            exit((getpid()+k)%100);
        }
        else
        {
            //Elternprozess liegt vor
            time_t curtime;
            time(&curtime);
            printf("Start: %s", ctime(&curtime));

        }
                    int exitcode=0;
                    //TODO bestimmen wie man auf alle aus der Liste wartet:
                     wait(&exitcode);
                     //exitcode to String casten:
                     char str[24];
                     sprintf(str, "Exit-Code: %d\n",WEXITSTATUS(exitcode));
                     //Ausgabe des Exitcodes:
                     write(STDOUT_FILENO, str, strlen(str));
                     time_t curtime;
                     time(&curtime);
                     printf("Ende: %s\n", ctime(&curtime));
                     return 0;
    }
```

Comment: Please post a [mcve].  In fact, just the act of trying to make an MCVE (i.e. removing one line or block at a time while making sure this bug still happens, will most likely reveal to you where the syntax error is.

Comment: `if(//TODO list)` Did you forget to replace some todo?

Comment: Why do you post text as image? Please don't post text as image.

Comment: The error says the exact line where it is. It says what it is (not about parens, about what’s missing before that paren).  Syntax highlighting shows what’s happening. There’s even a comment saying something’s missing. And MCVE doesn’t help much when fixing syntax errors, looking at the code does.

Answer (score 1):

I can see three issues in the code.

- `if(//TODO list)`  Because of the comment marker `//` the closing parenthesis `)` for the `if` is missing and also there is no condition for it.
- `srand((unsigned) time(&t));` `t` is undeclared here.
- `int help=rand()%(k*0.5);`. You are using a `double` (`k*0.5`) as an operand of `%`